# angular 4 Highcharts set yAxis Categories

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using angular4 and Highcharts  .
I want to create graph with two y-axis.

So :

1. It will show only one series of data
2. it will show 2 yaxis , one of them will have labels that I define (It have only 2 labels : 0 + max value)

how can I do that ?

I.e.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to understand _It have only 2 labels : 0 + max value_ can you explain

Comment: I need the second yaxis only to show labels ,I don't need it to realy be connected to a series

Comment: is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-dual-axis?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts&view=preview) your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dhsgo47z/

If you want the secondary axis to have the same extremes as the primary one then a good place add the new axis is a load event (because it doesn't utilize hardcoded values):

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var primaryYAxis = this.yAxis[0];

        this.addAxis({
          title: {
            text: 'Secondary'
          },
          min: primaryYAxis.min,
          max: primaryYAxis.max,
          tickPositions: [0,  primaryYAxis.max],
          endOnTick: false,
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.isLast ? "Maximum" : this.value;
            }
          }
        }, false);
      }
    }
  },
```

`tickPositiones` serves to set the exact positions of ticks (there'll be no more and no less than defined). `labels.formatter` is used to give the second tick a custom string value.

---

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addAxis
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter